# Excel averaging

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to average a cell where #N/A, 0, #NUM may occur. I want to write a code to average all the cell value when they are less than J24 cell value and greater than J25 cell value.

I have tried `AVERAGEIF(J2:J21,AND(">="&J25","<="&J24"),J2:J21)` this code. But I am getting #DIV/0 error. If anyone has any idea how to solve the issue, that would be a great help.

Thanks

[Error in Averaging cell B1 to B21, when they are greater than B25 and less than B24, while not including 0, #N/A, #NUM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLedH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your `#DIV/0` is likely due to incorrect range references.  You write about Column B, but your formula refers to Column J.

For a formula for column J, that ignores errors, you can try:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(1/((J2:J21>J24)*(J2:J21<J25))),J2:J21))
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the `AVERAGE` function will ignore Booleans.

[image]

Comment: This did not work for me. Do not know why.                                                                                                                                                                                         Later, I used this code and worked:                                   =AVERAGEIFS(J2:J21,J2:J21,">="&J25,J2:J21,">="&J25,J2:J21,">=0",J2:J21,"<="&J24)

Answer (score 0):

*This solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- An array (CSE) formula in cell M70:

  ```
  {=IF(ISNUMBER(M61:M69),AVERAGEIFS(M61:M69,M61:M69,">="&L61,M61:M69,"<="&L62),0)}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish the formula with **Ctrl+shift+Enter**.
- Operator `>=` & `<=` covers any number between 10 and 25.
- If you use `>` & `<` then it skip 10.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*